# If PayPal IPN Listener script finds duplicate payment, does PayPal cancel the transaction?

Tags: paypal

I am setting up paypal integration using IPN and just before my IPN Listener adds the IPN data to a database, I am using this code below, which checks to make sure the transaction isn't already in the database, and if so, it exits the script:

```
 //Check if payment data exists with the same TXN ID.
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT payment_id FROM payments WHERE transaction_id = ?");
    $stmt->execute([$transaction_id]);
    $num_rows= $stmt->rowCount();
    if($num_rows > 0){
        exit();
    } 
    //then more code to insert IPN data into database
```

What I am confused by is this:  If it DOES find that the transaction_id already exists and exits the script, does the payment still get processed and it just doesn't put any info into my database, or does it also cancel the payment on paypal's end?  Hopefully it's the latter, but if it's the former, how should this situation be handled, since the payment would need to be cancelled and I'm not sure how to go about getting that done.

Comment: is there any reason you are not using Web Hooks ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a duplicate *notification*. Paypal may send the notification more than once, but they only give you the money once, and you should only record the transaction once.